# Fetch all IDs and put them into an array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How do I get a SQL script to collect all the IDs from a field and put them in an array?

Comment: please.. please clarify your question. Are you trying to submit a form and want it in 'array' format? `name[]`?

Comment: What kind of database are you using, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we assume that the ID column is just called `id`, then try the following code (DB connection code ommitted for clarity):

```
$ids_array = array();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table_name");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $ids_array[] = $row['id'];
}
```

If you want to sort the IDs ascending or descending, simply add `ORDER BY id ASC` or `ORDER BY id DESC` respectively to the end of the MySQL query

What the code above does is iterate through every row returned by the query. `$row` is an array of the current row, which just contains `id`, because that's all we're selecting from the database (`SELECT id FROM ...`). Using `$ids_array[]` will add a new element to the end of the array you're storing your IDs in (`$ids_array`, and will have the value of `$row['id']` (the ID from the current row in the query) put into it.

After the while loop, use `print_r($ids_array);` to see what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options in PHP. The recommended one is using PDO library. You can use `PDO:FETCH_COLUMN` fetch mode.

```
// connect via PDO
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8mb4", $user, $pass, [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
]);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM test1');
$stmt->execute();
$ids = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

An alternative is to use mysqli. Try to avoid mysqli if you can. It is more complicated and it is easier to make a mistake. It doesn't have the same fetch mode, so you need to iterate over the result and append a single value to an array manually.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id FROM test1');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$ids = [];
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $ids[] = $row['id'];
}
```

Both approaches will give you a one-dimensional array of ids.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all of the IDs from a sqlQuery into an array, you would do something like this:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE...");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
   $array[]=$row['id'];
}
```